# Sorting an array that is in another array in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a `json` file called by `fetch` request that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "Infos": [
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105254"
            },
            "total": 142854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105255"
            },
            "total": 112854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "105256"
            },
            "total": 132854739
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "Id": "106540"
            },
            "total": 122868818
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want to sort data based on `total` field ,but as you can see all objects are in another array called `Infos` and I can not to sort data like this:

```
 Maindata.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total);
```

How can I sort data based on `total` field that is in another an array?

```
     class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        perPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,

    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'get',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            Maindata.sort((a, b) => a.Infos[i].total - b.Infos[i].total) // I want to sort data here /////

            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))

}

reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { perPage, data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
    this.setState({
        library,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    })
}



// Previous Page
previousPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    })
}
// Next Page 
nextPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
    })
}

// handle per page
handlePerPage = (evt) =>
    this.setState({
        perPage: evt.target.value
    }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

// handle render of library
renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div>NOResult</div>
    }
    return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
        <div className="Wrapper">{this.renderInfo(item)}</div>
    ))
}

renderInfo(element){
    let len =element.Infos.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      return element.Infos[i].total
    }

}

render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLibrary()}
            <ul id="page-numbers">
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {currentPage !== 1 && (
                        <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span className="fa-backward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
                <li className="controlsPage activeCnt">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
                <li className="restControls">...</li>
                <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
                        <button onClick={this.nextPage}><span className="fa-forward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the inner field by mapping over the outer array and sorting the inner one like

```
Maindata = Maindata.map((data) => ({Infos: data.Infos.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total)}))
```